# How to insert or replace many with Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hi I have an array of vehicles which I want to insert into my MongoDB. If a document with the same category already exists I want it to be replaced (updated).
This is my Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const vehicleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    category: {type: String, required: true},
    vehicles: {type: Array, required: true}
}, {
    toJSON: {
        transform: function (doc, ret) {
            delete ret._id;
            delete ret.__v;
        }
    }
});


const model = mongoose.model('vehicle', vehicleSchema);

module.exports = model;
```

This is what I currently have:

```
function insertVehicles(vehicles) {
    const vehicleUpdate = vehicles.map(vehicle => ({
        updateOne: {
            filter: {category: vehicle.name},
            update: {$set: vehicle},
            upsert: true
        }
    }));

    return Vehicle.bulkWrite(vehicleUpdate);
}
```

Currently when I try to insert the array it won't be updated if it already exists, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. vehicle.name did not exist, the correct property was vehicle.category.